# AFHTTPRequestOperationManager's Operations don't get the headers

Tags: ios, afnetworking, afnetworking-2

I'm using the following code to set up my operation manager:

```
requestSerializerJson = [AFJSONRequestSerializer serializer];
[requestSerializerJson setValue:[taskHandler getBranchesApiConstantForName:@"header_value_content_type"] forHTTPHeaderField:[taskHandler getBranchesApiConstantForName:@"header_name_content_type"]];
[requestSerializerJson setValue:[taskHandler getBranchesApiConstantForName:@"header_value_api_key"] forHTTPHeaderField:[taskHandler getBranchesApiConstantForName:@"header_name_api_key"]];

httpRequestOperationManager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];
httpRequestOperationManager.requestSerializer = requestSerializerJson;
httpRequestOperationManager.responseSerializer = [AFJSONResponseSerializer serializer];
httpRequestOperationManager.operationQueue = [[NSOperationQueue alloc] init];
httpRequestOperationManager.operationQueue.maxConcurrentOperationCount = 1;
```

Then, I've got a method to download multiple JSON strings:

```
- (void)downloadBranches {

    NSLog(@"Test %@", httpRequestOperationManager.requestSerializer.HTTPMethodsEncodingParametersInURI);

    for (NSString *branchUuid in taskHandler.addedBranchesUuids) {

        NSString *urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@%@", urlBase, [taskHandler getBranchesApiConstantForName:@"getbranch_suffix"], branchUuid];
        NSURL *URL = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];
        NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:URL];

        NSLog(@"Test %@", request.allHTTPHeaderFields);

        AFHTTPRequestOperation *op = [httpRequestOperationManager HTTPRequestOperationWithRequest:request success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {

            NSLog(@"JSON: %@", responseObject);

        } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {

            NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
        }];
        op.responseSerializer = [AFJSONResponseSerializer serializer];

        [httpRequestOperationManager.operationQueue addOperation:op];
    }
}
```

All the operations are performed but I get a message from the server which says that I didn't supply the authentication key.

I specifically set it in the 3rd line - for the `requestSerializerJson` which is then added to the `httpRequestOperationManager` so all of the requests should be using the headers.

I added an NSLog to print `request.allHTTPHeaderFields` but it says "(null)".

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`downloadBranches` is completely bypassing the serializer by building an `NSURLRequest` manually. The whole point of the serializer is to do that for you.

You need to call `requestWithMethod:URLString:parameters:` on your serializer, which will return an `NSURLRequest` with the headers you want.

Or just use the operation manager's `GET:…` method inside that `for` loop; your use case doesn't look like it requires this other stuff at all.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification - I had it all wrong. Just one more question, though: when I used AFHTTPSessionManager and its GET method, it seemed that there's no way of making sure all the requests are performed in a sequence, one at a time. Would GET on AFHTTPRequestOperationManager have the same effect or would it simply create a request operation which I could then add to the operation queue?

Comment: Neither the GET method nor your current code enforces one operation being run at a time.

Comment: You can set the operation queue's maximum concurrent operations property to 1; then either will accomplish this. Alternatively, you can schedule dependent operations in the completion handlers of the operations that get te data they need.